# Jenkins email-ext plugin add a trigger for a specific build failure

Tags: jenkins, email-ext

I have email-ext plugin configured on Jenkins. 
Currently I'm sending mails using following triggers.

- Failure-1st
- Failure-2nd
- Failure-Still
- Success

What I need to know, is there a way to add a custom trigger to send mails on a specific build failure

assume that I need to send a mail on build **Failure-4th**

Answer (score 1):

You can use Trigger Scripts in groovy to define before or after the build if the email must be send or not.
There are four objects added to the model for the script to use to interact with the build.

- build: This is the current build, usually a child class of `AbstractBuild`
- project: The project object that the current build was started from, usually a child class of `AbstractProject`
- rooturl: The Jenkins instance root URL, useful for links.
- out: A `PrintStream` that can be used to log messages to the build log.

The last line in the script should resolve to a boolean `true` or `false`.

So I guess you can do what you want if you use a Groovy Script.
For more info check: [e-mail ext](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)